# How can I remove an event listener in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm currently trying to remove an event listener on click on a button (see code below) but it never works, I know I'm supposed to use the same function to cancel the event (here keyboardControl) but it doesn't seem to be working at all.
Thanks in advance

```
    <button class="start">start</button>
    <button class="stop">stop</button>
```

```
    const start = document.querySelector(".start")
    const stopbtn = document.querySelector(".stop")

    start.addEventListener("click", () => keyboardControl())
    stopbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyboardControl)
    })

    function keyboardControl() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 37: //left arrow key
                    console.log("left")
                    break
                case 39: 
                    console.log("right")
                    break
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the same function to `removeEventListener` that you passed to `addEventListener`. The function you are passing to `addEventListener` is

```
(e) => {
        switch(e.keyCode) {
            case 37: //left arrow key
                console.log("left")
                break
            case 39: 
                console.log("right")
                break
        }
    }
```

Since you are not storing a reference to it anywhere you cannot remove it. Assign that function to variable and use that to add and remove it:

```js
const start = document.querySelector(".start")
const stopbtn = document.querySelector(".stop")

function handleKey(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37: //left arrow key
      console.log("left")
      break
    case 39:
      console.log("right")
      break
  }
}

function keyboardControl() {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKey);
}

start.addEventListener("click", () => keyboardControl())
stopbtn.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKey)
)
```

```html
<button class="start">start</button>
<button class="stop">stop</button>
```

---

Removing `keyboardControl` doesn't work for a multiple reasons:

- It's not actually the handler that you want to remove. The function adds another event handler, but removing it won't automagically remove the handler it added.
- `keyboardControl` is never bound as an event handler to `document`.